# firebase firestore nosql design for chat app with groups

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am trying to think of a way to design the firestore db in a way that is efficient.
The main issue I am having with is how I should define "groups". Lets say a user is invited to a group chat and so the client needs to retrieve the data for that group chat, should I have a "groups" collection and then find the correct group document? OR, should I have a "groups" property in the user document that has a id to reference the group to retrieve?

In SQL, having a reference in a user's groups table would be the obvious answer, but I am not sure about firestore. **I don't want to look through the entire collection of groups just to find the group that the user was newly invited in.** Any tips? Also, my front end is in React and I am considering using the onSnapshot method to subscribe to the collection (that seems to be the best way to have real time updates).

Answer (score 0):

What i believe is best for you is this :

First have a collection, suppose you make groups, and inside that every docuent has all the group unique ids,

And inside that for every group, i.e document, you can have a collection which holds all the chats for that group and group related info , like group type, etc etc

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

[image]